# Link Inside Bootstrap Model box not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, bootstrap-modal

I have created a Bootstrap Model box and a nested carousel, and have tried adding links so that when an image is clicked on, the link takes you to the original artist. But when the modal box pops up, the link is unclickable, and instead just closes the modal box. Is it possible to make the link clickable?

```
               <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104366.png" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Andrew. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/161720">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104367.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Andrew. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/161720">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104370.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Andrew. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/161720">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104854.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104855.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104856.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104857.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104860.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="images/imageGall/1104861.jpg" class="d-block w-100" />
                                        <p>Artist Name: Oreskis. More of his work can be found <a href="https://alphacoders.com/users/profile/194044">here</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you just missed out `<div class="modal-content">` between `modal-dialog` and `model-header`.
See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#live-demo.